# ElasticSearch and Sense - get results when a field is null

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I'm using elasticsearch 2.3.1, and trying to write a query to filter on `_score` field.

I need to check whether `_score` is **not null**.

Here is what i've tried:

**REQUEST**

```
POST /_search
{
  "from" : 0, "size" : 200,
  "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "_type": "monitor"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "_score": {
                  "value": null
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
  },
  "sort": {
    "TraceDateTime": {
      "order": "desc",
      "ignore_unmapped": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

**RESPONSE**

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "query_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "No value specified for term query",
            "index": ".kibana",
            "line": 18,
            "col": 15
         },
         {
            "type": "query_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "No value specified for term query",
            "index": "monitors",
            "line": 18,
            "col": 15
         }
      ],
      "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason": "all shards failed",
      "phase": "query",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [
         {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": ".kibana",
            "node": "IjGeW1YgSiiUY1devzlAgQ",
            "reason": {
               "type": "query_parsing_exception",
               "reason": "No value specified for term query",
               "index": ".kibana",
               "line": 18,
               "col": 15
            }
         },
         {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "monitors",
            "node": "IjGeW1YgSiiUY1devzlAgQ",
            "reason": {
               "type": "query_parsing_exception",
               "reason": "No value specified for term query",
               "index": "monitors",
               "line": 18,
               "col": 15
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Comment: `_score` is a field from your mapping? Have you tried `"must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "_score"
        }
      }`?

Comment: 1. _score is a known field of each document (like _type, _index and so on..). it's not part of my mapping. 
2. Your suggestion returns also _score = null documents

Comment: :-) that's not how it works, that's the score ES gives to each document given the search. You can't filter after score just like you do with other terms. Have you looked at [min_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html)?

Comment: Let's add something to the question : How to I get documents within range of _score ?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I get it. Thanks.
So we must add "track_scores" : true to each search ?

Comment: What's your use case? Do you need scoring? Why are you bothered by the score being `null`?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I do not need. Just want to learn about scoring.

Comment: Manipulating the score this way is not a common practice. The way you adjust the score is by indexing (and analyzing/tokenizing) the data in specific way and then using certain queries. After this, ES gives some scores to documents matching the query and gives you the results in specific sorting order.